# Determine HTTP version of incoming request in springboot webflux

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I’m looking for a way to find the HTTP version of incoming request in spring webflux netty server

I cannot find any method in `ServerWebExchange` to get this information.

Spring servlet has some implementation to get it as given in [springboot servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55847052/determine-http-version-of-incoming-requestentity-in-springboot-2-1).

Is it any possibility to get it in webflux implementation?